# For loop that uses elements of a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
nums = [2, 3]
for x in range(len(nums)):
    for y in range(nums[x]):
        print('sss')
```

Let's say i don't know the elements of the nums list. I have to use those elements to repeat the print function 2 times, and then 3 times. But the print function will be used more than that because it's already inside another for loop. Is there a way of doing this I'm confused.

Comment: Your code does print `sss` twice and then three times. Does it not for you?

Answer (score 3):

So for each item in `nums` you want to print `'sss'` that number of times?

```
nums = [2, 3]
for num in nums:
    for _ in range(num):
        print('sss')
```

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to the code in the question.

Comment: yeah...got confused with these ranges and indexes. Thanks

Comment: @Blender in that case I don't understand the question.